# How to dims the screen brightness into 0% and after touch from anywhere back into 100%

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app that will run always in the background and will dim the screen brightness to 0% after a certain period if the user does not touch within that time. And if user touch, the app will automatically dim the screen brightness back to 100%. How can I do that?